# 2nd order ODE with non-bounded solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find (if possible) $f$ such that $$y''(t)+y(t)=f(t)$$ only has non-bounded solutions in $\Bbb R$.

I just noted that if they have to be non-bounded none of them can be constant and I don't know what else to do. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Since the homogeneous solutions of your equations are of the form $t\mapsto \alpha\cos(t)+\beta\sin(t)$, with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, and thus bounded, it suffices to find a $f$ such that a particular solution of your equation is unbounded. Take $f(t)=e^t$, which leads to the particular solution $y(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^t$, and you can conclude.